# Do I use "Deductions" or "Income (loss)" for my business expenses?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

I have a new general partnership that has zero money coming in, but sustained losses for the year.  Does these go under "deductions", or under "income (loss)" on the 1065 IRS form?

The losses relate to costs incurred from operating the business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the expenses, you will enter them under *Deductions*, on lines 9 through 20.

Did you rent an office? Add the rental expense to line 13. Fee for a business license? Line 14. Everything else that doesn't fall into any specific category goes on line 20 (You'll need to attach a small statement that breaks out the expense categories, e.g. *office supplies*, *phone*, *legal fees*, etc.)

Expenses that are entered in the *Income* section are costs directly related to sales, such as merchant fees that you pay to a bank if you take payments by credit card. Since you said the partnership has "zero money coming in," I assume that it currently has no revenues, so all the fields in the *Income* section would be zero.

Comment: Based on this, it looks like I will have X deductions (let's say $1000), with zeros in the Income section.  One confusion I have is with the Schedule-K (page 4 of the "U.S. Return of Partnership Income" form): on page 4, line 1 (which is "page 1, line 22"), I'll put -$1000 since line 22 it is the sum of my income and deductions on page 1. But in page 4, line 13, if I re-enter my deductions, then line 1 on page 5 becomes -$2000.  Any ideas on how to avoid double listing the deductions?

Comment: Don't include any deductions in the *Deductions* section of Schedule K that you already entered on page 1 of the 1065. This section is only for additional deductions that apply to special cases.